# Android: onResume() is jumping to another activity than excepted

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, surfaceview, flashlight

I am developing a FlashLight App for Nexus & galaxy devices. 
The Application works on Galaxy but there is one thing that is going wrong.
When I set the application into background (by pressing home button) and then clicking the widget, it opens onResume from the mainactivity like you can see here:

[image]

So my quesions are:

1. How can I check if an activity (in this case FlashLight.java) is running?
2. How can I kill the running activity from invisible_activity.java?
3. Why is there onResume() from FlashLight.java called and how can I restrain this issue?

LogCat from the Red square:

```
    11-18 15:36:03.300: D/Camera(9781): app passed NULL surface
11-18 15:36:03.400: D/InputTransport(9781): Input channel constructed: name='ClientState{4366a1d0 uid 10141 pid 9781} (server)', fd=56
11-18 15:36:03.445: D/AndroidRuntime(9781): Shutting down VM
11-18 15:36:03.445: W/dalvikvm(9781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d26700)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe/spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe.FlashLight}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2918)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:413)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:384)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe.FlashLight.check_for_flash(FlashLight.java:82)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe.FlashLight.onResume(FlashLight.java:74)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1209)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5450)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781):     ... 10 more
```

**onResume() from FlashLight.java**

It's crashing at "cam = Camera.open();" when I click on the Widget.

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
 super.onResume();

 check_settings();

 if(light_ == 0){
        finish();
        Intent i_screenlight = new Intent(FlashLight.this, ScreenLight_noFlash.class);  
        startActivity(i_screenlight); 
 }else{
 mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    if(cam != null){

    } else {
        rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout_background);       
        cam = Camera.open();  //===> It's crashing here, when I open the widget     
        cam.startPreview();
        p = cam.getParameters();

        if(light == 1){     
            if(sound == 0){
                mPlayer.start();   
            }
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cmd_flash_light.setText(R.string.off);
                cmd_flash_light.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ein_2);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();

        } else {

            if(sound == 0){
                mPlayer.start(); 
            }
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cmd_flash_light.setText(R.string.on);
                cmd_flash_light.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ein);
                cam.setParameters(p);           
                cam.startPreview();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**Receiver, that calls the invisible_activity.java**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.flash_widget);

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,     FlashlightWidgetProvider.class),
                                                                         views);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe", "spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe.invisible_activity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);       
}
```

**invisible_activity.java (for the widget, that handles the led light)**

```
public class invisible_activity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private static Camera cam_;
    SurfaceView preview_;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    shell_preferences shellpreference = new shell_preferences(this);
    int isLightOn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.invisible);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        isLightOn = shellpreference.getInt("LIGHT_ACT", 0);
         if (isLightOn == 1) {
             if (cam_ != null) {
                     cam_.stopPreview();
                     cam_.release();
                     cam_ = null;
                     finish();
             }
             shellpreference.setInt("LIGHT_ACT", 0);

     } else {
             // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing cam_.
             cam_ = Camera.open();

                     // Set the torch flash mode
                     Parameters param = cam_.getParameters();
                     param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                    preview_ = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView2);
                    mHolder = preview_.getHolder();
                    mHolder.addCallback(this);

                    try {           
                        cam_.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                        cam_.setParameters(param);
                        cam_.startPreview();
                             shellpreference.setInt("LIGHT_ACT", 1);
                                finish();
     }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mHolder = holder;
        try {
            cam_.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(cam_ != null){
         cam_.stopPreview();
            mHolder = null;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that you forgot to handle releasing the camera when you actually destroy your app/activity.

try overriding onDestroy() for it:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (camera!=null)
    {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;
   }
}
```

At least your logcat is pointing to this issue:

11-18 15:36:03.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9781): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:           Fail to connect to camera service

Comment: try this: after you get this error above try loading the standard-camera-app on your device and check if it can connect or not. if not, your must upgrade your camera-releasing for sure!

Comment: So you mean I should simulate the error, then open the camera app? -> This is working or I should open camera app programmatically before the error cames up? -> Exactly same error

Comment: no i meant the standard camera-app that is already on your phone. The idea is that there can only exist one app using the camera at the same time. So basically when your custom-app doesnt release the camera properly, another camera-app can't connect to the camera. This is what i wanted to show ya!